# How to get document from cosmos db using SQL Rest API when the collection has partition key , but the partition key is empty for document?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, partition

I have tried with value as "null" and "Undefined.Value" but no success . I am using SQL REST Api for Cosmos and the collection has partition key that makes it necessary to add the header "x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey"  header with value of the key .
I am currently testing from postman

Comment: I am using SQL Rest API  version 2016-07-11

Comment: Did you try empty string?

Answer (score 0):

As per my tests, I created a CosmosDB with a partition of /pk.
I created 2 documents.

```
"id": "0001", 
"name": "Test1", 
"pk": ""

"id": "0002",
"name": "Test2"
```

My Rest API call was able to pick up id "0001" with a partition key of [""] but it was not able to pick up id = "0002" with the same partition key. This tells me that the 2nd scenario is where you are at. The items were written without mentioning the partition key and in such a case, you will not be able to fetch the data using the rest API. If you set the partition key as blank while inserting the document, you should be able to retrieve the documents.

In short setting "pk" to "" is not the same as not setting it at all.